# Allowed memory size exhausted concatenating var

Tags: php, pdf, memory, size, tcpdf

I am working on a project that generates PDF files. I am using the TCPDF library, with its method "WriteHTML".

To write the html, I do some like this:

```
$html = "";
for($i = 0; $i < $someBigNumber; $i++){
    $html .= "BigData"; //Here I do a concatenate 
}
$pdf->WriteHTML($html, paramaters);
```

But the problem is that if $someNumber is so big or the data is so big, there is a fatal error.

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 36 bytes)

Comment: Yes, it's funny the way that works isn't it; create a very big string in memory, and it uses.... memory.... if you absolutely have to create enormous strings in memory, then increase PHP's memory allowance; otherwise look to options like streaming data, or building a file and then loading that file to the PDF renderer

Comment: 134 mb of html is quite a bit of text

Answer (score 1):

Set configuration value `memory_limit = 256M` (or more) in your php.ini settings or .htaccess file (in root dir)

Comment: Probably want to include an `M` or else you are talking 256 bytes.